# Terminal error (some typo somewhere?) with .bashrc disables all aliases etc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I can't use any of my aliases or custom defined variables in bash. The error when I open the terminal is immediately:

```
: command not found
bash: /home/khaverim7/.bashrc: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'ash: /home/khaverim7/.bashrc: line 6: `case $- in
```

I may have added/removed a character somewhere in .bashrc when I last used my computer, but I have no idea where. I have tried copying a default .bashrc file and got a more complex error:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: invalid shell option name
: command not found
: command not found
: invalid shell option name
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
bash: /home/khaverim7/.bashrc: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'ash: /home/khaverim7/.bashrc: line 32: `case "$TERM" in
```

This is the current version of my .bashrc file which produces the first error above:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=15000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# MY CUSTOM ALIASES=====================================
alias lah='ls -lah'

alias fone="adb -d forward tcp:8080 tcp 8080;telnet -e '' 127.0.01 8080"



# MY CUSTOM FUNCTIONS ===================================
# opall: opens all files with supplied filetype in current dir (e.g. opall doc opens all .doc files)
function opall {
    ls -b *.$1 | xargs -n 1 xdg-open
}


# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Looks like you have Windows line endings (`\r\n`) instead of Unix line endings (`\n`). Did you edit those files on Windows at some point of time? Try the `dos2unix` command to convert.

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar and a gentleman. I don't know how this happened but `dos2unix` fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have Windows line endings (`\r\n`) instead of Unix line endings (`\n`). For example,  look at the first set of error messages:

```
... token `$'in\r''
'ash: /home/khaverim7/.bashrc: line 6: `case $- in
```

What it should be, if `\r` (carriage return, which sends the cursor back to the first character in a line) were printed as `\r`:

```
... token `$'in\r''
bash: /home/khaverim7/.bashrc: line 6: `case $- in\r'
```

Similarly,

```
: command not found
```

would be due the lone `\r` on an empty line:

```
bash: \r: command not found
```

And,

```
: invalid shell option name
```

would be due to a `\r` at the end of `shopt` command, where the option name is short enough:

```
bash: line 0: shopt: something\r: invalid shell option name
```

(Compare with `bash -c blah` and `bash -c 'shopt -s blah'`.)

To regain Unix line endings, use the [`dos2unix`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dos2unix) command to convert:

```
dos2unix .bashrc
```

I would suspect that you used a Windows-based client at some point (like WinSCP, FileZilla, etc.), or that your editor has defaulted to Windows line endings.