# Ubuntu saying file does not exist when it does?

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to access a file with this script:

```
cd /home/rust/servers/rust1/
screen -X -S old_rust quit
screen -dmS old_rust wine ./rust_server.exe -batchmode -cfg "./config.cfg" -port 28015 -maxplayers 75 -datadir "serverdata/"
```

Whenever I run the script, I get this error

```
rust@direct:~$ /home/rust/servers/rust1/start.sh
: No such file or directoryart.sh: line 1: cd: /home/rust/servers/rust1/
```

The directory `/home/rust/servers/rust1/` does exist and you can cd to it in ssh.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminal error (some typo somewhere?) with .bashrc disables all aliases etc](http://askubuntu.com/questions/549359/terminal-error-some-typo-somewhere-with-bashrc-disables-all-aliases-etc)

Answer (score 0):

> No such file or directoryart.sh

Since the script you're trying to call is start.sh, you have a typo somewhere

Comment: unless this is a copy paste issue

Answer (score -1):

As I can see you don't delimit your commands. You should delimit your commands with semicolon (`;`) or double ampersand (`&&`). The difference between the two is that when you delimit your commands with `&&`, then the next command only run if previous succeed, while `;` delimited commands run anyway.

So, you probably should write something like this:

```
cd /home/rust/servers/rust1/ && screen -X -S old_rust quit && \
    screen -dmS old_rust wine ./rust_server.exe -batchmode \
        -cfg "./config.cfg" -port 28015 -maxplayers 75 -datadir "serverdata/"
```